# ASp.net regular expression union. Can it be combined into one regular expression or should I do a custom validator to test 2 expressions separately

Tags: asp.net, regex

Need help with one regular expression that test 2 things .
1st is 8 characters where 1st character must start with W and has 7 zero padded numbers after.
2nd is a 6 character zero padded number.

I have the following two regular expression but not sure how to combine them
Not sure if best thing to do is to write a custom validator and evaluate the two expressions separately.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

The 2nd expression have below works only thing is that it validates 000000 which I don't want to

```
[W]\d{7} 
^[0-9]\d{5}$
```

Comment: IMHO this question is clear to answer. There are 2 patterns in the question that the OP wants to combine, and it should not match only zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You could optionally match `W` and a single digit followed by matching 6 digits asserting not only zeroes.

```
^(?!0+$)(?:W[0-9])?[0-9]{6}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!0+$)` Negative lookahead to rule out only zeroes
- `(?:W[0-9])?` Optionally match `W` and a single digit 0-9
- `[0-9]{6}` Match 6 digits 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pkL0PB/1)

Comment: Hey this works. omg thanks so much.need to break part each even though you explained them to understand it a little more. but just tested and it worked.